# Не выводит динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, динамические-массивы

Всем привет, задача вроде легкая но я перепробовал много способов и не смог решить. Нужно что бы все записывалось в s[i] а потом так же вывелось по индексам допустим пользователь ввел 2 записалось под индексом s[0] потом ввел допустим 6 и записалось в s[1] в конечном результате все индексы которые пользователь ввел вывести, когда пользователь ввел "end". Помогите пожалуйста второй день ломаю голову. Я знаю что num 0 и for не выполняется но я много чего пробовал и тоже не получалось я не знаю что делать..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string n;

    int num;
    int* s = new int[num];
    while (n != "end")
    {
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            cin >> s[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            cout << s[i];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. вы делаете

   ```
    int* s = new int[num];
   ```

а где вы получаете этот `num`?

```
std::cin >> num;
```

хотя бы сделали

2. вы делаете

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cin >> s[i];
   ```

что это такое? вы же должны вводить по ОДНОМУ числу

делайте

```
cin >> s[i];
i ++;
```

только перед циклом инициализируйте `i`

```
int i = 0;
```

3. вы делаете

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cout << s[i];
   ```

зачем вы выводите постоянно в цикле все это? выводить надо ПОСЛЕ того как закончен ввод всей последовательности

4. и еще хотя вы вначале выделяете массив из `num` элементов, но пользователь может ввести меньше кол-во элементов перед тем как введет `end`, поэтому выводить надо только введенные числа и только после того как ввод будет завершен
5. вы постоянно требуете у пользователя ввод `n`

   ```
    cin >> n;
   ```

чтобы проверит на ввод `end` - так делать не стоит

**P.S.**

вообще сначала пишите свой алгоритм текстом на бумаге и лишь потом пытайтесь его в код превратить

ваш алгоритм должен был бы выглядеть так:

1. запросить у пользователя максимальное кол-во элементов
2. выделить массив, содержащий максимальное кол-во элементов
3. запросить у пользователя ввод числа или `end`
4. если введено `end` - перейти к 8)
5. преобразовать введённую строку в число
6. добавить полученное значение в массив по заданному элементу
7. увеличить номер заданного элемента на 1
8. вывести все значения массива от 0 до номера заданного элемента

если же использовать std::vector, тогда

1. и 2) не нужны
2. и 7) заменяются просто на `arr.push_back(value)`

а 8) можно просто вывести через

```
for (const int value : arr)
```

Comment: Спасибо за детальную информацию но у меня есть пару вопросов... Вы написали "чтобы проверит на ввод end - так делать не стоит" а какая есть интерактива, желательно с string и как "преобразовать введённую строку в число" подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: std:atoi чтоб строку в число перевести